# Does this Infinite summation of Bessel function has a closed form?

Tags: bessel-functions

The summation is $$\sum_{n>0}\frac{J_n^2(x)}{n}\sin\frac{2n\pi}{3}$$ I found a thread [Infinite sum of Bessel Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806014/infinite-sum-of-bessel-functions) and a wiki article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerche%E2%80%93Newberger_sum_rule) may be helpful. However, I still cannot figure this out. Also see the description of [Bessel function of first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) at Mathworld, equation 61-66 may be helpful.

Comment: @Alizter By index you mean the $1/n$ in the front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neumann's addition theorem is given by
\begin{align}
J_{0}\left(\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} - 2 x y \cos\phi}\ \right) = J_{0}(x) J_{0}(y) + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n}(x) J_{n}(y) \cos(n\phi).
\end{align}
By letting $y=x$ it can quickly be sen that
\begin{align}
J_{0}\left(2 x \sin(\phi/2) \right) = J_{0}^{2}(x) + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n}^{2}(x) \cos(n\phi).
\end{align}
Integrate both sides with respect to $\phi$ to obtain the expression
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \, J_{n}^{2}(x) \sin\left(\frac{2 n\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3} \, J_{0}^{2}(x) + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi/3} J_{0}\left( 2 x \sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right) \, d\phi.
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice answer, same reason as the other thread, thank you very much!