# How to prove or disprove this infinite sum of Bessel functions is zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

The sum is $$\sum_{n>0} \mathrm{i}^n\frac{J_n(x)}{n}\sin\frac{2\pi n}{3}\stackrel{?}{=}0$$ and $$\sum_{n>0} (\mathrm{-i})^n\frac{J_n(x)}{n}\sin\frac{2\pi n}{3}\stackrel{?}{=}0$$

I suspect they are zero because I am working on a project which from symmetry consideration they should be zero.

**If anyone can point out they cannot be zero, or they cannot identically be zero, that will be great, too.**

I've asked a question about Bessel function before, see [Does this Infinite summation of Bessel function has a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985566/does-this-infinite-summation-of-bessel-function-has-a-closed-form) I hope the reference it contains may do some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the generating function
\begin{align}
e^{i x \cos\phi} = J_{0}(x) + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} i^{n} \, J_{n}(x) \, \cos(n \phi)
\end{align}
integration with respect to $\phi$leads to
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^{n}}{n} \, J_{n}(x) \, \sin\left(\frac{2 n \pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3} \, J_{0}(x) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi/3} e^{i x \cos\phi} \, d\phi.
\end{align}
The integral is not equal to $- \frac{\pi}{3} \, J_{0}(x)$, which leads to a non-zero result. For the second summation letting $x \rightarrow - x$ leads to
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^{n}}{n} \, J_{n}(x) \, \sin\left(\frac{2 n \pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3} \, J_{0}(x) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi/3} e^{-i x \cos\phi} \, d\phi.
\end{align}

Comment: This is very nice answer, I've noticed the generating function; however I've never managed to integrate it to get the expression I want.

Answer (score 1):

For $x = 1$, numerical evaluation of the first sum in Maple gives me
$$0.0502908663091560136488560173842+ 0.381051541033830840946600100117\,
i$$
so I can be pretty confident that they are not $0$.

Comment: This is pretty enough for me, thank you very much!